# Need to keep some columns editable and non-editable and allow cell editing on only double click on the cell

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecelleditor, defaulttablemodel

In my implementation of `JTable`. I have to keep some columns editable and some columns UN-editable so I have override `isCellEditable` -

```
@Override
public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
    if (col == uneditableColumn) {
        return false;
    }
    return bEdit;
}
```

Now my requirement is to allow edit the cell only on Double click i.e. if user double clicks on cell then only it comes into editable mode. For this - I will have to make your own `CellEditor` and override.

```
public boolean isCellEditable( EventObject e )
```

Can someone suggest if can be possible using -

```
public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col)
```

Please help -

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
is to allow edit the cell only on Double click i.e. if user double clicks 
on cell then only it comes into editable mode.
```

you have look at [DefaultCellEditor#clickCountToStart](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultCellEditor.html#clickCountToStart)

for CellEditor or methods override isCellEditable (AbstractTableModel)

```
@Override
public boolean isCellEditable(EventObject anEvent) {
    if (anEvent instanceof MouseEvent) {
        return ((MouseEvent) anEvent).getClickCount() >= clickCountToStart;
    }
    return true;
}
```

for DefaultTableModel could it be

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class EditorRendererClickCountToStart {

    public EditorRendererClickCountToStart() {
        TableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(new Object[][]{
                    {"A", "Item 0"}, {"B", "Item 1"}, {"C", "Item 2"},
                    {"D", "Item 3"}, {"E", "Item 4"}}, new String[]{"TextField", "Combo"});
        JTable table = new JTable(model);
        table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        DefaultCellEditor editor = new DefaultCellEditor(new JComboBox(new Object[]{
                    "Item 0", "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4"}));
        editor.setClickCountToStart(2);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellEditor(editor);
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            for (LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                System.out.println(info.getName());
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {// handle exception
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {// handle exception
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {// handle exception
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {// handle exception
        }
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new EditorRendererClickCountToStart();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: @kleopatra thanks, thats the question what's is really healthy on this world, hmmm,... I got it on 1st. place is laugh, then so long nothing only heaps of muck and on 2nd. place is Nutella ??? or ...., maybe, hard to decide :-)

Comment: @mKorbel Thanks. The editing has only restricted to the mouse click, sorry -- as I have asked so, but if user starts typing the text-using keyboard then table's cell is allowing him to do so. Can we restrict him for editing too using keyboard unless he do not double click the cell.

Comment: @Ashish Pancholi, Key F2 is about startCellEditing(put the info about that to the ToolTip), maybe this way :-), I think that is nonsence remove MouseListener from Cell, then better would be change editor.setClickCountToStart(int); to 10???, 20???, 50???, hehehe but I knows a few users that can pretty to forcing this restriction,

Comment: @mKorbel I did not understand your comment but I am accepting your answer because you have solved my issue. I actually need - if user starts pressing keys then Table search matching text for him and if user double click on cell then Table allow him to edit the text. - Is it possible ? Please help. Thanks

Comment: @Ashish Pancholi please before anything is there some chance that you'll be edit you question with SSCCE, or start a new question, because maybe there is/are bussines or logical issues, becasue your last comment isn't about user_friendly way, maybe I'm wrong up to you, code with sticked image is the best way....

Comment: @mKorbel http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9975339/please-help-me-to-allow-my-jtable-to-search-the-text-even-the-table-is-in-edit

Answer (score 3):

Well, I'd not override `isCellEditable(...)` in `JTable` but rather provide a custom table model.

From the JavaDoc on `JTable#isCellEditable(...)`:

> The column is specified in the table view's display order, and not in the TableModel's column order. This is an important distinction because as the user rearranges the columns in the table, the column at a given index in the view will change. Meanwhile the user's actions never affect the model's column ordering.

Additionally the cell might appear to be editable to the table but the editor itself might not provide input fields until it has been double clicked. If you want to make only one cell editable at a time you might store that information in the model as well and let the editors check that.