# Please help me to allow my `JTable` to search the text even the table is in editable mode on key-press

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecelleditor

If user starts pressing keys using keyboards then `JTable` is supposed to be searched the matching text for him and if user double clicks on cell then Table should allow him to edit the text.

And the issue is - Table is only searching text when the table is in non-editable mode and if Table is editable and user starts typing the text-using keyboard, cell is allowing him to edit the cell rather then search. [Mr mKorbel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/714968/mkorbel) has just solved my issue to [allow edit only if double click on Table cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9972643/need-to-keep-some-columns-editable-and-non-editable-and-allow-cell-editing-on-on).

Please help me to allow my `JTable` to search the text even the table is in editable mode on key-press.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
table.putClientProperty("JTable.autoStartsEdit", Boolean.FALSE);
```